# How to fetch data from a table created in Sencha MVC approach?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have a table in my database. I am adding the rows to a datastore created.

```
var journal_db = [];
var db;
```

This is my dataStore:

```
Ext.define('iPolis.store.journalStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: 'Ext.DateExtras',

config: {

    model: 'iPolis.model.journal',

    data : journal_db

}
});
```

I am adding the rows to my datastore like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
          row = results.rows.item(i);
        journalStore.add({'id':row['id'],'infoLine':row['infoLine'],'eventDate':row['eventDate'],'address':row['address'],'text':row['text'],'place':row['place']});

  }
```

It gives me a reference error Uncaught ReferenceError: journalStore is not defined.
Can anyone please help me to add the rows to the datastore?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create instance of store just before using it

```
var journalStore = Ext.create('iPolis.store.journalStore');
for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
     journalStore.add(results.rows.item(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, Sencha Touch understands `journalStore` as a variable. I cannot see it anywhere...so maybe it's really undefined.

To obtain your Store, simply add an id to your store definition, like: `id: 'journal-store'` and whenever you want to get it, simply use `Ext.getStore('journal-store')`.

Hope it helps.

PS: If your Store is not created automatically (through the config of other components, such as Ext.List), you have to explicitly create it. Add

`journalStore = Ext.create('iPolis.store.journalStore');`

and it should work.

Comment: journalStore is the name of my store. I had used the add method the same way when i was not following mvc pattern and i was able to add the row items to my datastore. Now i have given my datastore an id and used it like this: `var mystore= Ext.getStore('journal-store'); mystore.add({'id':row['id'],'infoLine':row['infoLine'],'eventDate':row['eventDate'],'address':row['address'],'text':row['text']});`
and now i see this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined.

Comment: I've checked it and saw that your store is not created yet. Try what I've just written. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where should i include the `journalStore = Ext.create('iPolis.store.journalStore');` so that the object of that journalStore class is created.